# Три приставки в слове

Tags: словообразование

«Вам, может, сие и непризаметно, а вот человека, бишь, со свежинки по носу бьет. [Анатолий Мариенгоф. Циники (1928)]».

В этой фразе бросается в глаза своей искусственностью очень редкое слово с тремя приставками. Столь же редки слова «понавострился», «понавывозили». Чтобы использовать подобные слова, честный человек должен делать ссылку на автора.

Существуют ли в русском языке общеупотребимые слова с тремя приставками, встречающиеся чаще, чем «неприсоединившиеся (страны)», «недопонимание», «позапрошлый»?

Answer (score 3):

Есть. Безусловно нормативно слово **предрасположенный**, хотя и тут могут возникнуть сомнения в отношении приставки "по", сросшейся с корнем. Больше искать не стал, не сильно интересно, ибо даже сами критерии "общеупотребительности" весьма размыты в данном случае.

Тут другое. А как эти приставки считать? К Вашему примеру, например, "непризаметный" есть претензии. "Непри" - скорее всего надо трактовать как единую приставку - по аналогии с "недо". А историческая приставка "за" здесь сильно слилась с корнем, так что можно говорить даже о морфемном переразложении. Так что из начитанных трех приставок остается хорошо если одна.
И такие вопросы - "А как считать-то приставки?" - будут возникать почти каждый раз, когда вы предложите подобным  образом сконструированное слово.
Очень сомнительно также включение в список **считаемых** приставок частицы "не" не потому, что это якобы не приставка, но по сути того, что она липнет к вообще любому слову.
Так что основной вопрос не в общеупотребительности, а именно в правилах вычленения приставок для такого счета.

Comment: behemothus, спасибо Вам за вопросы. Предлагаются следующие правила игры (для тех кому интересно):
1.Приставки определяем по этимологическим словарям (так в слове «способ» их будет две).
2.Слившиеся приставки разделяем (приставка «недо» засчитывается за две).
3. Приставка «не» идет в зачет, как любая другая «полноценная». 
4. Оценку найденному слову пусть ставит корпус русского языка. Количество баллов пусть будет равно числу вхождений слова в основной корпус.

Comment: Учитывается только одна, но самая упоминаемая форма слова. Например, слово «внезапный» имеет 932 вхождения, в то время как другая его форма - «внезапно» гораздо популярнее и упоминается 16048 раз.

Answer (score 2):

При большом желании можно ***понавыдумывать*** сколько угодно слов с тремя приставками:

*Купить хорошеньких тетрадок,

В них понавкладывать закладок,

Поназасушивать цветков,

Поназаписывать стишков,

В них понавклеивать картинок...

Такую славную тетрадь

Так утешительно читать,

Когда вокруг смотреть противно...*

А общеупотребительные слова, конечно, есть:
**невпроворот, недооценка, безосколочный, переосмысленный, повыспросить**...
[Слова с тремя приставками](https://chastislova.ru/slova-tri-pristavki.html)

Есть интересное, спорное, на мой взгляд, слово — [дидодекаэдр](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%80).

Comment: Вопрос поставлен для отыскания слов «естественного происхождения». А вот «расподпонавыдумывать» слов и в самом деле можно сколько угодно. А за отклик, все таки, спасибо.

Comment: Так я Вам и дала ссылку на слова _естественного происхождения._ Недооценить, переосмыслить и проч. — часто встречающиеся слова.

Comment: Простите великодушно, не заметил. За ссылку отдельное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Наличие трех приставок в слове вряд ли должно удивлять.** Достаточно вспомнить, что приставки не только имеют собственную семантику, но и используются для образования совершенного вида глагола, то есть выполняют грамматическую функцию, например: *думать ― задумать ― призадуматься.*

Среди приставок на третьих ролях часто встречаются следующие:  ПО (повторяемость действия), НА (избыточное действие), ПРИ (направленность действия).

2) Наречие ***непризаметно***   соотносится  с глаголом ***призаметить*** и является синонимом наречия ***неприметно***.

**Приставка ПРИ** имеет значение приближения действия к объекту, направления действия на объект (приметить/призаметить для себя).

**НЕПРИМЕТНО** I нареч.  Так, что трудно или невозможно заметить, увидеть; незаметно.  Толковый словарь Ефремовой.

У Маяковского можно встретить редкий глагол ***призаметить*** , семантика у ***приметить*** и ***призаметить*** немного разная. Возможно, этот глагол  сейчас устарел (или уже тогда относился к авторским неологизмам и употреблялся редко).

[Чудаков, муж] Смотри, ты ***призаметил*** эти две линейки, горизонтальную и вертикальную, с делениями, как на весах? [В. В. Маяковский. Баня (1929-1930)]

3) ***Понакупили, понаехали, понавострился*** ― приставка ПО в этих глаголах имеет значение распространения действия на многие объекты или значение повторяемости действия в разное время:  попрятать,  повыбить, **повыдергать**, **понабросать**, помёрзнуть, попадать.

Answer (score -1):

Вовкулака (во'в'к'у'лака)... А рассмотрите такие слова: рассудок, предрассудок.  
Знали бы вы про "и-", "я-", "е-"... есть утверждения, что если эти гласные стоят перед приставкой, то такая связка должна приниматься за три приставки. Например: "если" (е''с'ли), "явь" (я''в'ь). Поэтому в слове "искусство" - семь приставок!

Comment: 1. _Знали бы вы про "и-", "я-", "е-"... есть утверждения..._ А есть ли возможность с этими утверждениями ознакомиться? 2. _Поэтому в слове "искусство" - семь приставок!_ Корень-то тогда (по определению) какой?