# Дѝдодека́эдр — это особенное слово?

Tags: словообразование, орфоэпия, морфемный-разбор, приставка, корень-слова

[**дѝдодека́эдр**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%80)
Геометрическое тело, ограниченное 24 гранями (иногда оговаривается, что грани являются равносторонними треугольниками).
Корень: **-ди-**; корень: **-до-**; корень: **-дека-**; корень: **-эдр-** [Тихонов, 1996].

Отвечала на вопрос [Три приставки в слове](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447216/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5), попалось вот такое непростое.

1. Так [три приставки](https://chastislova.ru/slova-tri-pristavki.html) или четыре корня в слове "дидодекаэдр"?
2. А фитюлечка над **ѝ** — это знак какого-то *особенного* ударения?
   Как произносить такие слова и много ли их?

Answer (score 3):

Дидодекаэдр - сложное слово с 4 греч. корнями: ди(с)-дважды; додека-12 (здесь уже два корня в нашем представлении); эдр - грань.

Но в современной науке такие корни, как -эдр, часто называют **аффиксоидами, в данном случае суффиксоид,** потому что корень стоит на месте суффикса и выполняет его роль. Числительное здесь всё-таки корень, а не приставка, ведь с ним связано основное значение слова.

При образовании новых слов аффиксоиды выступают как готовые структурные элементы, причем в конечном итоге в качестве аффиксоида может выступать любой компонент чистых сложений и сложных существительных.

Примеры префиксоидов: авто-, био-, гидро-, микро-, кино-, теле-, фото-, электро-, теле-, видео-, пневмо-, бальнео-, баро-, крио-, водо-, все-, лесо-, много-, перво-, рыбо-, само-, тепло-, игло-, климато-, лавино-, луно-, плането-, фондо-.

Примеры суффиксоидов: -логия, -лог, -граф, -графил, -грамма, -метр, -метрик, -скоп, -фон, -бус, -тека, -воз, -провод, -вед, -вод, -ход, -мер, -ведение, -строение, -водство.

У нас корень -эдр тоже готовый структурный элемент: тетраэдр, гексаэдр (куб), октаэдр, додекаэдр, икосаэдр.

Сложные слова со многими корнями часто произносятся с двойным ударением, одно из которых называют побочным. Кстати, то, что ударение не падает на корень -эдр, тоже говорит о слабеющем значении морфа как корня, главное ударение на числительном - двойное 12. Побочное ударение играет разную роль, в том числе облегчающую  произношение, здесь, скорее всего, она и есть. Побочное ударение факультативно, это  словарь рекомендует:

дѝдодека́эдр